# iOS6 beta and continuation of developing

Tags: ios, app-store, ios6

I'm wondering if it's possible to try out the iOS6 beta on my device but still be able to develop my application (test it on my device running iOS6 beta) and have it submitted to the AppStore.

I'm not intending to install Xcode 4.5 to develop for iOS6 beta. I just want to try out the iOS6 beta on my device.

EDIT:

I noticed [this](https://superuser.com/q/435456/139822) thread on SuperUser. I will try that approach when I get back home from work and let you know if it's possible.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily have two versions of XCode installed in your system (I have installed both XCode 4.4 and XCode 4.5 beta 3) and my iPad is updated to iOS 6. I can test current apps on my iPad (this is, apps we're working in now) and deploy them, using XCode 4.4 of course. These apps must have a target of iOS 5.5.1 or under and mustn't use any iOS 6 additions.

Installing both XCode versions is quite easy, as the release one ( 4.4) is installed by Mac App Store and beta one (4.5) is installed as a .app file which you can drag & drop into your Application folder. It has a different name so it won't overwrite your 4.4 version.

For XCode to recognize your iOS 6 device you have to open 4.5 version, let Organizer collect data of your device and later you can open XCode 4.4, it will recognize that device image and use it (although you can't develop on iOS 6 with XCode 4.4, you CAN test an iOS 5 app on a iOS 6 device)

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to debug your code on iOS 6 device with your current Xcode. You need Xcode 4.5 for that.

Comment: So is it possible then to have 2 versions of Xcode installed? Xcode 4.5 to be able to debug my application on iOS6 beta. And Xcode 4.3.3 to be able to submit my application to AppStore?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, since your device with iOS6 can't be used for development with Xcode 4.3.3, so you can't archive your application.

Comment: That is "dumb". Many people must want to try out the new iOS betas and still be able to develop their applications. So if you want to try out the beta and still be able to develop your application you would need to have two devices then? One with beta installed and one with final release installed?

Comment: That's exactly true, like I said, I just updated the new iPad to iOS6 to have a look, but an hour later I already went back to 5.1.1 because I have to use it in development... kinda sucks though

Comment: @woutr_be what are you talking about? You don't even need a device to make an archive. The case of two Xcode versions where one is used for playing around with new sdks and another one to actually build and submit apps to AppStore is perfectly acceptable and very common scenario. Devices have nothing to do with that, but of course it's always the best to have separate devices for deployment and beta testing.

Comment: Yes, but his looking to keep Xcode 4.3.3 and still use his iOS6 device for development and to play around with, that's not possible

Comment: Does anyone have a definitive response to this? Can we install iOS6 and then debug and test our 5.x app using Xcode 4.5, then reopen the project in XCode 4.3, built and submit?

Comment: Well, I could keep 4.3.3 and also install 4.5 if that's possible? But in that case I would need to install Mountain Lion beta right. So can you run 4.3.3 under Mountain Lion and also 4.5 at the same time?

Comment: I was waiting for @FilipRadelic to comment back, I didn't find any way to install iOS6 and still use Xcode 4.3.3 to develop on the same device.

Comment: @woutr_be how did you go back to iOS 5? The Apple docs say you cannot go back to iOS 5.x once iOS 6 is installed on the device. I would like to give it a try too, but would probably want to go back to iOS 5 as well.

Comment: @Dennis You can easily restore your dive in Xcode's Organizer, just download the .ipsw and restore your iPhone / iPad

Comment: @PeterWarbo - Yes, it's absolutely possible to have 2 versions of XCode installed.  I forget the exact steps, but basically somewhere during the install process you have the option to change the default install location for XCode.  Change it to something that will not overwrite your existing XCode install, and you're set.  Note that for some things (like the "UNIX Dev Support" binaries) you cannot modify the default install location (so you'll end up with the latest version only), but in practice I haven't seen this cause any issues.

Comment: @woutr_be you can have both 4.3.3 and 4.5 installed on Lion, use 4.5 to test on your iOS 6 device, and 4.3.3 to submit to the AppStore. Or since Apple is still signing SHSH for iOS 5.1 while iOS 6.0 beta is active, you can just restore your device from either Xcode or iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

if you develop on xcode 4.3.3 and device user  iOS6 beta. you can add iOS6 software image in Organizer menu for app test on device iOS6 beta.

but you cannot develop iOS6 in xcode 4.3.3

Answer (score 0):

This version of iOS is intended only for installation on development devices registered with Apple's Developer Program. Attempting to install this version of iOS in an unauthorized manner could put your device in an unusable state, which could necessitate an out of warranty repair.
Devices updated to iOS 6 beta can not be restored to earlier versions of iOS. Registered development devices will be able to upgrade to future beta releases and the final iOS 6 software.

Xcode 4.5 Developer Preview cannot be used to submit apps to the iOS or Mac App Store. Continue to use the publicly released version of Xcode to compile and submit apps to the App Stores.

Xcode 4.5 Developer Preview and iOS 6 beta are pre-release software and are considered Apple Confidential Information and are subject to the terms of your iOS Developer Program License Agreement. Unauthorized distribution or disclosure of Apple Confidential Information is prohibited.

Check this for more details https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action#betadownloads